# How to get logs for Compute Engine API errors?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am a total beginner in cloud service management, so this is a very basic question.
I have inherited a kubernetes based project running in Google Cloud. I have discovered recently that there are millions of errors I am unaware of in `APIs & Services` > `Compute Engine API` > `Metrics` menu:

[image: Brutal amount of errors]

I have tried searching for these values both on google in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp) to no avail. With no link to the list of logs and hundreds of sub menu items I feel completely lost on where to start.

How can I get more information about these errors?

**How can I navigate to the relevant logs?**

Answer (score 1):

Your question is rather general so I will make some assumptions and educated guesses about your project and try to explain.

This level of error with API calls is of course unusually high and suggesting that some things don't work (for example someone deleted a backend service but left the load balancer without any health checks and it's accepting requests from the outside but there's nothing in the backend to process them).

That is just an exmaple - without more details I'm not even speculate further.

If you want to read more about the messages take the second one from the top - [documentation for `compute.v1.BackendServicesService.delete`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/beta/backendServices/delete).

You can also [explore other Compute Engine API methods](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/beta) to see what they do to give you more insight what is happening with your project.

This should give you a good starting point to explore the API.

Now - regarding logs. Just navigate to [Logs Viewer](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer) and select as a resource whatever you want to analyse (all or a single VM, Load Balancer, firewall rule, etc). You can also include (or exclude) certain level of logs (warning, error etc). Pissibilities are endless.

Your query may look something like this:

[image]

Here's more [documentation on GCP Logs Viewer](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview) to help you out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am going to check up on these and maybe I will be able to get more details. My problem was as stated: I was seeing a huge number of errors without any clear path to see the error messages _themselves_. The load balancer idea might be the actual solution: I was seeing some ingress in the **Kubernetes Engine > Services & Ingress* menu displaying `Some backend services are in UNHEALTHY state`.